# How can I return x arguments FROM a function?

Tags: lua, arguments

I am currently making a function to wrap the return value of another function. I dispose of the first few arguments, but after those, I want to store all of the following arguments. (the amount of arguments may vary)

```
        local _, _, from, _, _, ... = computer.pullSignal("modem_message")
        return table.unpack(arg)
```

However, I do not know how to do store all the following arguments.
Using ... is not yet an option, as it requires a name.

I tried to use ... (after the arguments to dispose of) to store all of the arguments following the previous arguments, and then use `table.unpack(args)` to return all of the arguments stored by ..., however, I received the error
" expected near '...'"
I do not know how to define a name for ...

Answer (score 3):

Your pseudo-code

```
local _, _, from, _, _, ... = computer.pullSignal("modem_message")
do_something_with(from)
return table.unpack(arg)
```

may be implemented as

```
return eat_head_and_return_tail(computer.pullSignal("modem_message"))
```

if you defined the following helper function:

```
local function eat_head_and_return_tail(_, _, from, _, _, ...)
    do_something_with(from)
    return ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
local result = {computer.pullSignal("modem_message")}
```

Packs the return value(s) into a table, which can then be accessed by index number, or, if pullSignal() is your function, just return a table with named properties:

```
function computer.pullSignal(str)
  return {val1 = "some", val2 = "number", val3 = "done"}
end
```

and pick out the one's you want to pass on to the next function, or, whatever function you pass the return value to knows which members to use:

```
function analyzeReturn(returnTbl)
  local a,b,c = returnTbl.val1,returnTbl.val2,returnTbl.val3
  doSomething(a,b,c)
end

analyzeReturn(computer.pullSignal("modem_message"))
```

Also, "..." is known as a vararg, as in variable number of arguments, as in function arguments

```
function myFunc(a,b,...)
```

Variable names can't start with or contain periods, so not sure how you even thought

```
local _, _, from, _, _, ... =
```

would work.